# Angular 5 Material Table with Sortable Headers

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I was recently tasked with creating a component that displays a list of employees in a table format, using data from a hard coded JSON data object first, as well as how it would be done using data from a web service. Additionally, a button labeled 'Show(/Hide)' Employees needs to be included, allowing users to toggle the employee list table, with the value of the button, being based on the visibility of the employees table. Here is how the table should look:

[Employee Data Table Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4djEL.jpg)

Now I immediately went online and began looking at tutorials regarding Angular datatables and seeing whether anyone has attempted to do something similar because of course someone has. And I found and followed along with this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSt9CI3BXv4. This tutorial is doing exactly what I need and using a web service to do it.  (By the way this tutorial uses the prefix 'user' for directory and file naming but I use the prefix 'employee' since the component I'm tasked to develop is about employees.) I am able to get all the way through this tutorial, but at the end, the data from the web service is not displaying in the table for me. When I check the network results I see the data is being returned from the web service, it just isn't displaying for some reason. I will post what I think you most likely want to see, and I will add to this post whatever you need to see, but the entire code base is available at my github repo https://github.com/cmazzochi81/employeeApp

Thank you I appreciate your time,
CM

employee-table.component.html

```
<div>
  <mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{employee.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{employee.username}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{employee.email}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary">
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-header-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

employee-table-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {MatSort, MatSortable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {EmployeeService} from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-table',
  templateUrl: './employee-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeTableComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'username', 'email'];

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployee().subscribe(results => {
      if(!results){

        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
    })
  }

}
```

employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Employee} from './models/employee.model';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

private serviceUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getEmployee():Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.serviceUrl);
}
}
```

employee.model.ts

```
export interface Employee {
    name:string;
    username:string;
    email:string;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your html:

Your are defining the mat-row inside the mat-header-row, as you can see:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary">
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</mat-header-row>
```

and the correct way is:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

You have to close the mat-header-row before starting mat-row declaration.

Check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-gumjid)